# Mobile option to view site in fullscreen (wordpress theme: twentytwelve)

Tags: wordpress, mobile, plugins, web, fullscreen

I have modified the twentytwelve theme for its responsiveness on a website. I like it, but my client would also like the OPTION on a mobile to view the website in full width.

Is that possible? Maybe with a plugin?

Maybe somehow I can put a link on the mobile website which removes the "viewport" meta tag so it'll be viewed in full screen?

Answer (score 0):

To create a version of the website that is NOT responsive you can go into TwentyTwelve's style.css file and edit the media queries.

Scroll down to the media queries section and edit the "min-width" property, which is by default set to 600px.

Basically that query is saying that for every browser width larger than 600px, the full desktop version of the site will be shown.

If you change the min-width to be 1px, for example, the desktop version will always be shown.

Comment: I understand that, but I want the mobile version to stay. I want an second option (maybe a link) to view the site in full width also on mobile. Any ideas on this?